# Failed to connect ESP8266: Invalid head to Packet (0xf0) D:

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I am working with an arduino, rather learning to use it, I bought the esp8266 module to transmit data over wifi, but every time I upload a script it throws me the following error:

Failed to connect ESP8266: Invalid head to Packet (0xf0)

The selected port does not exist or the board is not connected

I already installed the drivers and libraries, select the COM4 port and checked in the device manager that it is correct.

As I was asked, here is the code I am trying to use.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

void setup()
  {  Serial.begin(115200);
     BT1.begin(115200);
  }

void loop()
  {  String B= "." ;
     if (BT1.available())
         { char c = BT1.read() ;
           Serial.print(c);
         }
     if (Serial.available())
         {  char c = Serial.read();
            BT1.print(c);
         }
   }
```

I connected the arduino via usb, the esp8266 using the breadboard, it is an ESP8266 ESP-01.

I hope you can help me.
(It's my first time on this site, sorry for the lack of info the first time)

Comment: is the esp-01 in flashing mode?

Comment: I advice to try a different USB cables. I had similar issues in the past and having a good quality cable turned very big factor in hte reliability of flashing. Beyond that, if what is written in the following link is correct, it is possible that you have a defective module.
https://www.reddit.com/r/esp8266/comments/34jcw8/invalid_head_of_packet_failure_when_flashing/

Comment: Juraj im using an Arduino UNO, I suppose not

Comment: find some tutorial. there are thousands on esp-01

Comment: i had resolve it thanks guys

Comment: @JavierGarcia , what was the issue and how you resolved it . I am facing same issue.